# IBM CONNECTIONS - Develop an extension that manage folders in file sync connector

Tags: ibm-connections

does anyone know if there is some way to develop an override of the default behaviour of the sync application?
Basically, I want to manage FOLDERS not just FILES as it does right now.

I know that the social & community part is quite extensible, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: hi Luca, you should look at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_folders_ic50&content=apicontent  the Folders API is extensive, and the best starting point for you

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks a lot for your suggestion, I'll try take a look to the reference you linked, but I don't understand, I have to write an external program where I include those API functionality or I can develop a program inside the IBM Connection environment that override the behaviour i don't like?

Comment: Folders is an existing feature.  If you want to build an extension to sync the Folders, you would have to use the API.

Comment: Folders are currently NOT supported in the sync environment, but a couple of IBM technician told me that they are in the roadmap in the next months.

Comment: Correct - you can build your own sync for folder